# Bootstrap responsive grid are not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to set mobile layout in which i am trying to place a textbox with a width of 75%; and a search button of 20%;

but it is not working

I am having extra space in the right and left in the div

[image]

```css
.green {

  background: green;

  height: 300px;

}

.yellow {

  background: #ffcc00;

  height: 300px;

}

.left {

  background: #147cc4;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;

}

.right {

  float: right;
  width: 20%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">

  <div class="col-md-4  green">

    <div class="left">
      hello world !
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      waka!
    </div>


  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: what change you required in current result

Comment: Why are you using some arbitrary `left` and `right` classes when you can use the grid, that's what it's for...

Comment: i am having a extra space in the right and left and i am attaching a screenshot kindly check it !

Comment: Go back to the bootstrap docs and learn more about it, you can do this properly if you spend a bit more time reading. You don't understand how to use cols properly.

Comment: Actually what do you need, ? cant understand your question,,

Answer (score -1):

**Solution**

You have to use media query at different different screen size. I am using maximum width at 400px.. But i suggest you have to use bootstrap for this.
**CSS**

```
    .green{
        background:green;
        height:300px;
    }

    .yellow{
        background:#ffcc00;
        height:300px;
    }

    .left{
        background:#147cc4;
        width:70%;
        font-size:30px;
        color:#fff;
        //left:0;
        float:left;
    }
    .right{
        float:right;
        width:20%;
        background:#fff;
        color:fff;
        font-size:30px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) 
    {
    .left
    {
        width:70%;
        font-size:15px;
        float:left;
    }
    .right{
        float:right;
        width:20%;
        font-size:15px;
    }
  }
```